# CFLDAP filter with equal sign

Tags: coldfusion, filter, ldap

I'm stuck on a problem where I need to make a filter to find a DN that doesn't have a "DC=blah" string.

so I have:

```
(!(distinguishedName='*DC=blah*'))
```

But that is not getting through well.

Help please!

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to put asterisk in the search string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed like there was NO WAY to get the DN filtered to way I like it so I had to use second filtering method using CFQUERY.

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="secondFilter">
SELECT * FROM firstFilter WHERE dn NOT LIKE '%DC=blah%'
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 1):

An excellent question. The negation filter you seek is `(!(distinguishedName=dc=blah*))`. A backslash cannot be used in an assertion unless it is followed by two hexadecimal characters. The quotes are not necessary unless they are part of the assertion.

This will work if `distinguishedName` is an attribute. Otherwise, DN components must be used in an extensible match filter. For more information, see ["LDAP: ldapsearch"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/), ["LDAP: Mastering search filters"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/), and ["LDAP: Programming Practices"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/).

Comment: Hello, I've tried that but it was not returning any results. I've tried in so many different ways but it just doesn't seem possible using filter by itself. Finally, I just had to use 2-step to get the list filtered, last step being another filtering function provided by ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it here, but maybe try this

```
(!(distinguishedName='DC\=blah'))
```

Comment: That is not working. I'm getting the same message as before, which is "Bad search filter"